# get the User data who logged in

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

so i have this database along with this code. this codes will enable a user to login to a page with session.
LOGIN FORM(login.php)

```
<?php
    require("common.php"); 
    $submitted_username = '';
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $query = "
            SELECT
                id,
                username,
                password,
                salt,
                email
            FROM users
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";
        $query_params = array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username']
        );

        try
        {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
        $login_ok = false;
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']);
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
            {
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            }

            if($check_password === $row['password'])
            {
                $login_ok = true;
            }
        }
        if($login_ok)
        {
            unset($row['salt']);
            unset($row['password']);
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            header("Location: private.php");
            die("Redirecting to: private.php");
        }
        else
        {
            print("Login Failed.");
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        }
    }

?>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username:<br />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" />
    <br /><br />
    Password:<br />
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
```

Session(common.php)

```
<?php

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "phplogin";


    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
    try
    {
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
        {
            foreach($array as &$value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
            }
        }

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    session_start();
?>
```

Display page(private.php)

```
<?php
    require("common.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        die("Redirecting to login.php");
    }
?>
<?php
    $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            email,
            task,
            task_name
        FROM users
    ";

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<h1>Memberlist</h1>
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>E-Mail Address</th>
        <th>Task Name</th>
        <th>Task Description</th>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['task_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['task'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>

        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table><br />
```

what i wanted to do is to display the data of the user who is currently login. for example is when user1 logged in every details in his profile lng username, email, task, and task name will be displayed but in my code it will display everyones detail.

Comment: Do you want to display all users who are logged in or the details of the user who logged in now ?

Comment: the person who is currently logged in/now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your private.php page change the query something like this :

```
$query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            email,
            task,
            task_name
        FROM users 
        WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'
    ";
```

Here `$_SESSION['user']['id']` Contains the id of logged in user, So only fetch the details of that user using `WHERE` in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` query is wrong

```
$query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            email,
            task,
            task_name
        FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'
    ";
```

no need of `foreach`

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($rows['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($rows['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($rows['task_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($rows['task'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['user']` is actually an array so I guess it should be something like : `$_SESSION['user']['username']` in your query